# How migrate from Xdebug version 2 for 3

Tags: php, xdebug

I read the from [Xdebug about the new version 3](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) and the difference from 2, try many combinations, but not work how version 2, where I click in debug and application start the debugger stopping in my breakpoints and display variables and values.

I receive a error when I try start the server:

> Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger' has been
> renamed, see the upgrading guide at
> https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger
> (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)

Now, the debugger is not work and I do not know how to solve.

This is my old configuration to version 2

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "10.224.100.252"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = "xdebug"
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_log = "/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.collect_params = On
xdebug.collect_return = On
xdebug.collect_vars = On
xdebug.dump_globals = On
```

This is my new configuration to version 3

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.trigger_value = ""
xdebug.log_level = 7
xdebug.discover_client_host = false
xdebug.client_host = localhost
xdebug.client_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = "xdebug"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000 
xdebug.collect_return= true
xdebug.dump_globals = true
xdebug.client_discovery_header = ""
```

This is my current version from php with Xdebug:

```
PHP 7.4.13 (cli) (built: Nov 24 2020 12:43:32) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

And I'm using this IDE

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-202.7660.26, built on October 6, 2020
```

Comment: Have you tried updating your IDE? XDebug 3 has been released in Nov 2020, and PHPStorm has received support about a week later in v2020.3

Comment: 1) What OS you are on? 2) Please post **whole** Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured in the same way you are trying to debug (a web page or CLI -- it's important as on Mac & Linux it's very common to have different php.ini for different env; If you are on Windows -- it depends on what you use) 3) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and share the log -- it will tell where it tries to connect to (if it tries that at all) and what the response is. 4) IntelliJ IDEA will be the same as PhpStorm here, so check such questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xdebug+phpstorm

Comment: Check these links as well: they are for PhpStorm but applied to IntelliJ IDEA as well: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: It is also helpful to put `xdebug_info();` in a file, as it will tell you which modes are active, what the value of settings are, and which INI files have been loaded.

Comment: In your old config you have `xdebug.remote_host = "10.224.100.252"`, and in your new one `xdebug.client_host = localhost`. Unless you meant to change that, that's where a problem could be.

Comment: In the original one you have `remote_autostart=1` on, but in the new one you have `xdebug.start_with_request=trigger`. To obtain the same behaviour, you need `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` as per the upgrade guide: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_autostart